# StoreKit frameworks

Tags: ios, storekit

Is there any good and full working iOS framework to easily manage inApp purchases (including auto-renewable subscriptions) out there? I excluded MKStoreKit, it is bad documented, too old and not maintained since a long time.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, look at [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) it's rather good.

Note: Be careful with auto-renewable subscriptions, it seems they are intended for the Newsstand apps [only](http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions).

Comment: good answer. Anyway this is a simple wrapper over StoreKit. This does not automatically manage subscriptions (duration, expiration ecc).